# Creating Gmail users in Google Apps without using my Domain for their addresses

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I am hosting my organization's website with someone who will not allow me to change the MX records. But I have verified my domain.

Google Apps provides me only `user@mydomain.com` e-mail accounts which need changes in MX records to work.

How do I create users with `user@gmail.com` accounts in Google Apps?

Answer (score 3):

You don't. You can't create @gmail.com addresses that are managed in Google Apps. Your only option as it stands is to use the @my-domain.com.test-google-a.com aliases that Google Apps creates for each my-domain.com email address you create. Obviously, this is not a good long-term solution.

It's really not OK that your host won't let you mess with your DNS records. You control/own your own domain name, right? You can transfer your domain to a domain registrar which will allow you to manipulate your DNS records, while retaining your actual web hosting where it is now.

Comment: Indeed, most domain registrars allow DNS management, so finding another one to switch to will not be hard.

Comment: Alternatively, you can register a second domain for just the email addresses, like `mailmydomain.com`. Not pretty, but if everything else is impossible. Then set up this as a secondary domain in the Google Apps control panel.